# C# Poll() method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a service class in a MVC 4.5 project. In this class I need to start a Poll method.

What is the best practice in doing this?

This is a mock up, but it needs to be started, and Thread.Sleep is not recommended. And the method should be global, and only one call for each minute.

```
    private void Poll()
    {
        Foo("Do somethings");
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
        Poll();
    }
```

Any good suggestions?

Comment: Its going to take a **very** long time, but this will eventually throw a `StackOverflowException`. Avoid unbounded recursive methods, depending on what this does, there are probably other ways to solve it.

Comment: I have a feeling that whatever you're doing would be best done in a Window Service and not within an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: I suspect you mean `Poll`, not `Pool`. If so, [How to run Background Tasks in Asp.Net](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) is probably a good read

Comment: Sorry.. Yes it is Poll.

Answer (score 2):

Using your approach will eventually result in a `StackOverflowException`.

You should leverage the built-in `Timer` class.
You can [find the documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Your usage code would be something like

```
Timer t = new Timer(o => Foo("Do somethings"), null, 0, 60000);
```

**Side note:**

As @RonBeyer pointed out, perhaps polling in an ASP.net might not be the best tool for the job you need to accomplish.

A WCF long-running service for instance with web-hooks to your ASP.Net application would seem appropriate. Again, it depends on what you need to achieve. Don't hesitate to complete your question with more details about what's your ultimate goal.

Comment: I'm not sure a `Timer` is the best approach in an ASP application...

Comment: It depends where in the application, and it depends what the application does. I would say that _Polling_ in an ASP.Net application can be arguable, yes, but it seems this is what the OP needs to do and he might have a good reason to do it.

Comment: I will try this solution.. Ill get back.

Comment: Is the best practice to call the method from the client, where I have a poll function in JavaScript.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve,  but  it is generally the preferred approach. Or having asynchronous code with Web sockets

Comment: Can I do this with Web Sockets? How?

Comment: For now I call it from the JavaScript Poll function.. But I would prefer that this was hidden from the client.

Comment: I went for the client side poll() function, and it works fine. Thanks for helping.